# Cisco EPC3010 suddenly stopped working; stuck on "scanning". ISP claims everything is fine

Tags: networking, modem, cable-modem

A few days ago, my internet connection suddenly dropped. I was not using it at the time, nor have I made any changes to my network recently. My computer is connected directly to the modem using an Ethernet cable, excluding router issues as the source of the problem. The modem is fed by a coax cable from an ISP-supplied splitter.

Attempted troubleshooting:

- Resetting the modem
- Calling the ISP (Telenor Norway / Canal Digital). They say everything looks fine from their end.

Blinkenlight status:

- Power: solid green
- DS: blinking green
- US: blinking green
- Online: off
- Link: solid green

Screenshots of the configuration site:

- [Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cixuk.jpg)

  - Status: "Scanning"
  - Downstream: ~8 dBmV, SNR ~40 dB
  - Upstream: ~40 dBmV
- [Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53YlN.jpg)

For the record, I've also posted this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/fmwxlz/cisco_epc3010_suddenly_stopped_working_stuck_on/).

Comment: Your ISP is clueless. Go and call them again.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Anything in particular I should mention? I suspect I'll just get the same answer if I call again without adding anything to the above.